# react native android release apk can't receive data from Internet

Tags: android, react-native, apk, release

I developed an app with React native and install debug apk in my device and all of the things are ok.

but when install release version in my device, it can't get data from API.

what's wrong?

Comment: Have you added the `INTERNET` user permission in the manifest? That permission is automatically added in the debug APK by React Native, so it would explain why it works in debug but not in release.

Comment: it exists in the manifest. are you mean that the debug manifest is different to release manifest?

Comment: React Native adds some permissions automatically at build time, check here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/removing-default-permissions

Comment: INTERNET permissions automatically added in manifest and work in debug. but I don't know why it can't get data from api in the release apk?

Comment: Are you using any specific HTTP client to consume your API like `axios` or `wthatwg-fetch`?

Comment: no, I use normal fetch

Comment: @MateiRadu your comment save my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 33):

In my case, I call api with non secure (http instead of https). So api work well for debug environment, but not work for release. You can add this line

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to AndroidManifest.xml

like that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
      ...
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      ...
```