# React native flat list don't show data screen after generating a release ApK

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I'm using react-native, and everything was working well while I was developing, but, when I built the APK (using this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content) and installed it on my device, 
the flat list don't show any data 
everything is working well the login screen connect to api the loged in
so the api work well 
so why the flatlist don't show any data 
. Did anybody had the same issue?

[image]

[image]

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCoffeeCategory()
  }

//flatlist code
    <FlatList
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          horizontal={true}
          data={this.props.data}
          renderItem={this._renderListItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}

        />
```

Comment: can you console.log or print this.props.data in UI?

Answer (score 1):

this is work with me 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56801525/7483108

In my case, I call api with non secure (http instead of https). So api work well for debug environment, but not work for release. You can add this line

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
to AndroidManifest.xml
```

like that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
      ...
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      ...
```